# How does Subaru hold his own against Felt?

Tags: re-zero

Considering his confession that he was a good for nothing NEET in a later episode before Rem re-motivates him, how/why does he have the physique and competence to hold his own Jackie Chan style against Felt?

Comment: It was revealed to us that for some reason he has a strength greater than he's used to in the real world. There's really too much factual information we don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While he is a NEET, he does mention in an early episode that he's not a complete shut-in, and does take some effort to keep in shape. That, combined with a slight increase in physical ability that apparently came to him in the new dimension are apparently enough for him to hold his own against Felt in that instance.